# Getting ID from database (my sql) returns null

Tags: java, sql

```
    private UUID getClientID(String username) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT id FROM `client_table` WHERE username=" + username;
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        return UUID.fromString(rs.getString(2));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Hi, here is my code and the section of the database I am trying to grab: http://prntscr.com/ezbomi. I want the ID but it is returning null. I'm thinking it is because of the query - any idea?

Comment: Maybe `rs.getString(0)` works?

Comment: You have to call `Result#next` (and check its return result) so as it get the first row (if one exists) - I would strongly recommend having a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and 
[JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) - Also, since you're only requesting a single column, you should be using `getString(1)`, which will be the first column

Comment: it should be String query = "SELECT id FROM `client_table` WHERE username=" + "\"" + username + "\";" ;

Comment: @rotgers Unlike just about everything else in Java, `ResultSet` is `1` based, meaning the first column is `1`, not `0`

Comment: `username= '" + username + "'"` works, but you should use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection attack.

Comment: @John Or just make proper use of `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well I don't know Java, but that seems just odd.

Comment: @rotgers It catches me out almost every time I come back to jdbc and it's one feature I really don't like

Comment: @MadProgrammer haha, it always makes me wonder what they were thinking while developing such a thing... Let's make it 1 index based, ye good idea, we will confuse them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Dropped the quotes. Unless you have a good reason not to, you should always make use of prepared statements. Any particular reason you tried to access the 2nd element from the ResultSet?

```
private UUID getClientID(String username) {
    try {
        //drop the extra quotes in the SQL statement
        String query = "SELECT id FROM client_table WHERE username = ?";
        //added prepared statement
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        //use 1 to access the first result from the result set
        return UUID.fromString(rs.getString(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You need to call (and check the result of) `ResultSet#next` to get the next row from the `ResultSet`, if one exists
- You need to use `1` instead of `2` when getting the column value, as you've only requested a single column and column indices start at `1`
- You should make proper use of `PreparedStatements`, parameters and bind the value to the statement
- You should make use of `try-with-resources` to manage your resources and make sure you clean them up when you're done
- I'd consider throwing the `Exception` rather than catching it, it would having more meaning than just returning `null`

For example

```
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM `client_table` WHERE username=?")) {
    stmt.setString(1, username);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    if (rs.next()) {
        return UUID.fromString(rs.getString(1));
    }
}
```

Have a look at:

- [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)
- [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

for more details

Answer (score 0):

You should move your ResultSet cursor before getting the data. The cursor is initially pointed before the head.

```
rs.next();
return UUID.fromString(rs.getString(2));
```

Comment: The query is broken, so this alone will not help

Comment: You're also not checking the result of `next`, as it may return `false` if not results where found